# On action error message not showing on same page

Tags: validation, struts2, validationerror

I have insert and view on same page. but problem is error message not showing

```xml
<action name="ViewAllCostings" class="volo.tms.costings.Costings" method="ViewAllCostings">
                  <result name="success">/costings/costings.jsp</result>
</action>     

<action name="addcosting" class="volo.tms.costings.Costings">
    <result name="input">/costings/costings.jsp</result>
    <result name="success" type="chain">ViewAllCostings</result>
    <result name="error" >/costings/costings.jsp</result>
</action>
```

and costings.jsp

```jsp
<s:actionerror/>
    <s:form action="addcosting" method="post">
    <s:textfield label="Costing Type" name="costtype" required="true"/>
    <s:textfield label="Cost(rs.)" name="costrs" required="true"/>           
    <s:submit value="ADD" name="addcostbutton"/>
</s:form>

<div class="Wrapper">           
    <display:table id="txt" name="costinglist" pagesize="10" cellpadding="2px;" cellspacing="5px;" requestURI="">
        <display:column property="costtype" title="Cost Type" sortable="true"></display:column>
        <display:column property="costrs" title="Cost(rs.)" sortable="true"></display:column>               
    </display:table></div>
```

and action class

```java
 public String execute(){//used this method for insert data 
        ArrayList costList = new ArrayList();
        costList.add(costtype);
        costList.add(costrs);
         costList.add(costid);
         if (AddCostDao.insertEditCostDetails(costList)) {
            return SUCCESS;
        } else {
            addActionError("Employee name already exists !");
            return ERROR;
        }}

public String ViewAllCostings(){ 
   //used for view data using list
    return SUCCESS
}
```

did not getting error message. I tried but not getting solution

Comment: can you show your action class?

Answer (score 0):

You might have validation errors which results `INPUT`, but the action is not executed and message isn't set. If you want to prevent the action from validation you can configure the action to exclude the method from validation interceptor. As far as validation interceptor implements a method filter interceptor  you can do it in `struts.xml`. Or just add `@SkipValidation` annotation on the method.

```java
@SkipValidation
public String execute(){//used this method for insert data
```